# Is it possible to open my phonegap app at a specific time?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am wondering weather or not it is possible to open a phonegap app I have created at a specific time on a specific page without using push notification

Comment: Do you mean to open app after specific time or open page in app ?

Comment: Open a page in the app at 7pm for example